# How to find a location around another place by time and distance search in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a situation, where i have certain location (y) is in the database (lat and lng) now i want to search a place ( lets say x) and need to search locations nearby (x) by time or distance (like 10min or 10km also (driving or walking)) to (x).

So get all the y's near x (by time or distance).

Is there a clean or simple way to do that.
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried creating a store locator? https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1

Comment: Sorry, i didn't but is it necessary to create a store first.All i need is to check that the locations that is in my database are nearer to a certain point or not (like 10 min or 20 min away&&| 10 km or 20km away ).

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9486727/2674883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!
Can be done using google maps

> direction api 
>   and 
>   matrix api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix

> one or more locations separated by the pipe character (|), in the form
>   of an address, latitude/longitude coordinates, or a place ID: