# How to calculate within distance with sql statement using Haversine formula

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( ".$_GET["lat"]." ) ) * cos( radians( ".$_GET["lng"]." ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( ".$_GET["lat"]." ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 0.5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1";
```

Based on my quick run through with death lol I realized my $_GET doesnt make sense as to what it's doing. The original formula is such

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

I can't find any good tutorials on how to implement this. I just need to know where to put it! My latitude and longitude.. in the sql statement so it can calculate IF around each other to group together.

[This is the google tutorial I got the code from.](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator?csw=1#finding-locations-with-mysql)

And a members [answer to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486581/proximity-search-google-map).. I feel there was hardly explanation on how to use this formula in sql..

**UPDATE**

I don't mean to bash. I know they explained it rather obvious, I just lack the ability to understand it for some reason. Much apologies links.

**UPDATE**

Still having troubles. I tried adjusting the code as such. Is this being done right? Cause I insert two geolocation coords that are the same and they should group together, but are not.

```
<?php
    $lat1=$_GET["lat"];
    $lng1=$_GET["lng"];
    $lat2=$grouping[$counter][1];
    $lng2=$grouping[$counter][2];
    $sql = "SELECT id, status, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat1) ) * cos( radians( $lat2 ) ) 
    * cos( radians( $lng2 ) - radians($lng1) ) + sin( radians($lat1) ) * sin(radians($lat2)) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 0.5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 2;";
?>
```